# The (relativistic) mass of a proton in the LHC

Tags: mass, large-hadron-collider, protons

What would be the (relativistic) mass of a proton, in grams, as it is traveling at the maximum possible speed in the LHC?

Comment: The same as for a proton at rest. Relativistic mass is an old concept that isn't being used anymore. If you want to do a quick and dirty one, the max. proton energy is 7TeV, which is about 7000GeV/0.938GeV or approx. 7460 times the rest-mass energy of the proton.

Comment: http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/mass-energy-matter-etc/more-on-mass/the-two-definitions-of-mass-and-why-i-use-only-one/

Comment: The mass is about $1.67\times10^{-24}$ g.

Answer (score 6):

Let's consider two separate things:

- The mass (i.e. rest mass) of anything doesn't depend on its relative
  motion to an observer (i.e. is Lorentz invariant). For a proton, $m_p\simeq 1\,\text{GeV}/c^2$.
- The energy (occasionally egregiously called mass or relativistic mass in old-fashioned sources) of an object isn't Lorentz invariant. In the future, the LHC will collide protons with 
  $$E / c^2 =\gamma m_p \simeq 6.5\,\text{TeV}/c^2$$ 
  energy each, in the laboratory frame.

Note that the conventional unit for particle masses is $\text{eV}/c^2$. You can convert between units with this conversion factor
$$
1.782 661 907 \times 10^{-36}\,\text{kg} = 1\,\text{eV}/c^2 
$$
and this [table of SI suffixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix#List_of_SI_prefixes) for T, G etc.

Comment: Okay, I understand the difference between invariant mass and relativistic mass. Now, is the radial force required to keep a proton in its orbit in the LHC a function of its invariant mass or its relativistic mass?

Comment: John: The best way to think of it is as a function of *momentum*. Because $\vec{F} = \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\vec{p}}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ holds in both Newtonian and Einsteinian mechanics. Then you use $\vec{p} = \gamma m \vec{u}$. In the old way of talking you would have folded the $\gamma$ with the $m$ and called the result the "relativistic mass", but due to the nature of the Lorentz transform the transverse inertia is different from longitudinal inertia.